# RAM is getting crahsed while applying .split() to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split, google-colaboratory

I want to tokenize the text in "BULLET_POINTS" column separate by space, for that I used the bellow code. But it leads to huge usage of RAM and getting crashed. I'm using Google Colab. Here "df_Train" is a pandas dataframe.

```
# import re
def tokenization(text):
    tokens = text.split()
    return tokens
#applying function to the column
df_Train.loc[:,'BULLET_POINTS']= df_Train.loc[:,'BULLET_POINTS'].apply(lambda x: tokenization(x))
df_Train.head()
```

Comment: How many rows and columns do you have?

Comment: @TimRoberts (2903024, 5)

Comment: And are these very long strings?  3 million rows of 80 character strings would be 1/4 gigabyte.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes

Comment: Where did the data come from?  Can you do this split before you take it into a dataframe?

Comment: @TimRoberts it is in ".csv" format, I think I cannot do that.

Comment: Why not?  You can filter the CSV one line at a time, at which point it can be sucked into a dataframe without needing fancy manipulation.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am totally unaware of it, it will be really helpful if you could elaborate more on this.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a few lines of your CSV file, and then post what you expect your dataframe to look like.